# jQuery pause in loop of array until previous item is ready

Tags: jquery

Hey im new to jQuery and i hope my title made sense :P. i need to have a pause in this loop until the previous iframe in the array is ready before next one gets is src. here is some of my code i think its reasonably close but im missing something.

```
enter code here

var url = [
    "http://www.stuff.co.nz/" ,
    "http://www.metservice.com/marine-surf/tides/nelson"
];

$(function()
{
    $("iframe").each(function(index)
    {
        if (index == 0)
        {
            $(this).attr('src', url[index]);
        }
        $(this).ready()
        {
            $(this).attr('src', url[index]);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You can not control when an iFrame loads. That's not possible.

Comment: Replace this code block  `$(this).ready()
        {
            $(this).attr('src', url[index]);
        }` with `$(this).ready(function(){
            $(this).attr('src', url[index]);
        }); 
        `  do increment the `index` within each loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to wait for the iFrame's load event, and then fire the next iteration, somthing you can't do easily inside an each() loop, so using a recurring function seems better

```
var url = [
    "http://www.stuff.co.nz/",
    "http://www.metservice.com/marine-surf/tides/nelson"
];

$(function () {
    var iframes = $("iframe"),
        i = 0,
        l = iframes.length;

    (function fn(elem) {
        elem.load(function() {
            if (i<l) {
                fn( iframes.eq( elem.index(iframes) + 1 ) );
            }
        }).prop('src', url[i++]);
    })(iframes.first());
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/YWxFk/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
$(function() {
   var totalFrames = $("iframe").length;

   function setURL ( index ) {
      $("iframe:eq("+index+")").attr('src', url[index]);
      $("iframe:eq("+index+")").load(function () {
         alert('iframe loaded');
         if ( index < totalFrames ) {
            setURL( index );
         } 
      });

   }
   setURL ( 0 ); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    function loadFrames(index)
    {
         if(index>=$("iframe").length)
            return;
         $("iframe").eq(index).attr('src', url[index]);
         $("iframe").eq(index).load(){
           loadFrames(index++);
         }

    }
    $(function(){
      loadFrames(0);
    });
```